# Multiple Variable Assignment in Javascript/GAS - Is this the most compact way to do it?

Tags: google-apps-script

Ok so I have a spreadsheet which we extract a 2d array of values from.
But really I want one variable per line of this 2d array.
The following code does work... but is this the best way to do it?

```
function testAssignments(){
  config = ss.getRange("C2:C6").getValues();//2D Array
  result = []
  config.forEach(x => result.push(x[0]))
  var [a,b,c,d,e] = result;
  console.log(a,b,c,d,e);
}
```

I also tried the line `config.forEach(x=> x=x[0])` but that didn't work for some reason.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the direct answer for `is this the best way to do it?`. So I answer as a comment. As another direction, how about the following sample scripts? 1. `const v = config.reduce((o,[c],i) => (o[String.fromCharCode(97 + i)] = c, o), {})` In this script, the values can be retrieved by `v.a, v.b,,,`. 2. `config.forEach(([c],i) => this[String.fromCharCode(97 + i)] = c)` In this case, the values can be retrieved by `a, b,,,`. But in this case, these variables are declared as the global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.flat` instead of `.forEach` and `.push`. If you want a different variable name for each  element, there isn't a  better way.

```
const [a,b,c,d,e] = ss.getRange("C2:C6").getValues().flat();//1D Array
//or
const [[a],[b],[c],[d],[e]] = ss.getRange("C2:C6").getValues();
```

Comment: thanks! so clean looking!